# Standard no of users can access Maintains Management System within one minute

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I tested the one endpoint in the JMeter tool, and I found 16000 users can access within one minute without error and good throughput value. I want to know that no user count is possible for the Maintain Management System web application.

Answer (score 1):

Hammering one end-point doesn't have anything in common with the real scenario of application usage, well-behaved applications tend to [cache](https://web.dev/http-cache/) responses and go just-in-time optimization for particular calls.

You need to ensure that each JMeter thread does what real user of your "Maintain Management System web application" would do, i.e. :

1. Open login page
2. Perform login
3. Do some business actions
4. etc.

And don't forget to pay attention to:

- Handling of embedded resources (images, scripts, styles, fonts, sounds, etc.) as this is the most "heavy" content when it comes to web applications, you can enable this on the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or even better [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults))

  [image]
- Add [HTTP Cache Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to represent browser cache
- Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to deal with [Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- Add [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send the headers real browser would send
- Add [Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers) to represent real user ["think time"](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time)

Once you have the script which exactly mimics the real user start with 1 user and gradually increase the load until you see increasing response time or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first, this would be the maximum number of users your application can support.